# What's going to be new for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04

I haven't been able to find information about Ubuntu 11.04. Is it already decided what's going to go into Natty Narwhal?

Answer (score 5):

Others have pointed out the uds-n sprint page already, so I will concentrate on answering information on how best to determine what might be in 11.04

We have a [remote participation page](http://uds.ubuntu.com/participate/remote/) so that users can follow along with the sessions. Every session on [the schedule](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-n/) will have a corresponding IRC channel and a live audio stream.

For certain sessions that we think might be interesting to users we [publish video proceedings](http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/posts?view=archive&nsfw=dc) of the sessions for each UDS, along with the plenary presentations. This should give you an idea of the process that Ubuntu developers use to select features for 11.04.

Once the blueprints are selected you can monitor the [burndown charts](http://people.canonical.com/~pitti/workitems/natty/all.html) (broken down by person and team) to see how progress of your favorite feature is coming along.

Answer (score 2):

It is very early in the release cycle so not much has been decided about the next release. You can see the planned features in the [11.04 blueprints page](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty) on launchpad.

Most of the details of the changes will be decided in the Ubuntu Developers' Summit ([UDS-N](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-n/)). It will start on the 25th of October and finish on the 29th. It is being held at the Caribe Royal in Orlando, Florida, USA.

As usual, videos of the UDS will be posted online and there will be IRC channels allowing you to join in with the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

While still celebreting the birth of Maverick, maybe its too early to answer this question. Ubuntu Developer Summit will be held on 25-29 October and thet have a busy agenda: https://launchpad.net/sprints/uds-n/+specs We need some time and patience, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Many shiny new things.

That's about as specific as anybody can be at the moment because even if somebody could say what they'd like to pull in or upgrade, chances are there still needs to be some development work.

But one major thing I will mention: 10.10 was supposed to be the first gnome-shell based release. Gnome v3 didn't make it out on time and they pushed back for March 2011... So there is a good possibility that Gnome 3 might make it into 11.04.

Whether or not gnome-shell becomes the default desktop manager is a completely different question that probably only the design team can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I read that a new sound theme was probably being made. Here: http://mikebuntu.blogspot.com/2010/08/ubuntu-needs-new-sound-theme.html

That's all I know, though...